# Delegating org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions class

Tags: java, junit, delegates, junit5

I am writing a test automation framework, and trying to simplify life for my users as much as possible. I would like my users to just assert as regular Junit 5 test, and the log writing (my instance of Log4J), report entry (Extent Report) will all be done within the assert.

So, I would like to delegate org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions class so that:

```
assertTrue(myCondition, "My Message");
```

Will do the following (I copied the original `assertTrue` and added my functionality):

```
package org.junit.jupiter.api;

@API(status = STABLE, since = "5.0")
public class Assertions {

   //...... Some original org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions functions 

   public static void assertTrue(boolean condition, String message) {
      try{
          AssertTrue.assertTrue(condition, message);
      } 
      catch(AssertionError error){
         //Do my things - reporter and logger
         throw error;
      }  
  }
  //...... Some original org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions functions  
}
```

However

1. `org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions` is a long class to delegate.
2. it becomes complicated since `AssertTrue` is only visible in package level.

Would like to get some fresh thoughts on how to resolve it elegantly....
Thanks,

Comment: Did you look into the TestExecutionExceptionHandler? Maybe you can write an extension for this. https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#extensions-exception-handling

Answer (score 0):

OK,
What I ended up doing was creating a new `DelegatingAssert` class, and for every Assert I was interested, I created the following:

```
public static void assertFalse(DelegatingExtentTest testCase, boolean condition, String message) {

    try{
        Assertions.assertFalse(condition);
        testCase.pass(message);

    }
    catch(AssertionError e) {
        testCase.fail("Did not: " + message);
        getLogger().error("Fail message: " + e.getMessage());
        getLogger().error("Fail stack trace: " + Helper.getStackTrace(e));
        throw e;
    }

}
```